# Android Studioで、VSの「次のステートメントの設定」の機能は？

Tags: android-studio, debugging

割と最近、Android Studioを使い始めることになった者です。
Android Studioには、Visual Studioで言う「次のステートメントの設定」に該当する機能は無いのでしょうか？
一応「次のステートメントの設定」機能について説明しておきますと、デバッグの際、カーソルで特定のステートメントを指定して、次に実行するはずの行以外に強制的に飛ばしてしまう機能です。既に実行した行をもう一度実行させることも出来ますし、逆にスキップさせることも出来ます。ただし別の関数に飛ばすことは出来ません。要はIPレジスタの書き換えです。
Android Studioでは、文言からして「強制的にカーソル位置まで実行」がそれらしいのかと思いましたが、「まで」という言葉がそれらしくなく、試して見ると案の定違っていました。(普通の「カーソル位置まで実行」と一体どう違うのでしょうか...??)
今まで使ったデバッガには全て該当機能がありましたが、これだけ至れり尽くせりなAndroid Studioに、まさかこの機能がない...!?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEAベースだから、Evaluate Expressionのことでしょうか、デバッグタブのカーソル行まで実行アイコンの右隣りあたりに有る四角いアイコンをクリックして、デバッグ中に任意のコードを実行し結果を表示する　機能や名称などが違っていたらごめんなさい。

Comment: 返事が遅くなり済みません。折角ですが、それではありません。変数の値関係ではなく、「次にどの行を実行させるか」の制御を、強制的に変更しようというものです。